# Not able to redirect to home page using javascript after form submission in contact page

Tags: javascript, html, django

This is my contact.html page code:

```html
{% block body %}
<form action="/shop/contact" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">
<h1 style="text-align:center;margin:10px">Contact Us</h1>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
  <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="desc" class="form-label">Comments and Feedback</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary feed">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my javascript code in contact.html:

```js
<script>

$('.feed').click(function(){
    window.location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/";
    alert('Thank You for your comment or feedback. We will definately try to improve or will reach you out regarding this issue.');
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This window.location.href statement is not working to redirect me to shop(or home page). I cannot change my form action to /shop because I want form data to be stored in contact page only. So what can I do??

Comment: are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Nope not getting any errors.. alert box is also working properly

Comment: btw you can redirect to other pages from the backend.

Comment: how?? How can I go that?

Comment: show your views.

Comment: read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples

Comment: Thanks It's working after adding redirect function in my views, but what if I already have my return statements specified, like this:   `def contact(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        desc=request.POST.get('desc','')
        client_form=Contact(desc=desc)
        client_form.save()
        return render(request, "shop/contact.html",{'contact_id':567})
        # return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/')
    return render(request,"shop/contact.html")`

Answer (score 0):

Yes window.location.href is able to change the url text in browser, use window.location ="url" for redirection.

Some keys points need to keep in mind like you are using $ so, jQuery should be there at runtime, I mean you neee to include jQuery before this statement.